# Wrong result produced by stl max_element algorithm

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, max

I noticed a strange behavior of the **std::max_element** on the integers, which differ no more than one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
    std::cout<<*std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end())<<"\n";//it's ok - correct answer  
    std::cout<<*std::max_element(v.begin(), v.begin()+1)<<"\n";//compare between 1 and 2: answer - 1
    std::cout<<*std::max_element(v.begin()+1, v.begin()+2)<<"\n";//compare between 2 and 3: answer - 2
}
```

I use **gcc 4.8** compiler on **64-bit linux**.
Is this compilers's bug, or something else?

Comment: Those are one-past-the-end iterators you're passing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually correct behaviour, just note that `v.end()` is basically one **past the last element** and that means, it is not included. The same is true for `v.begin()+1` - it's not included, it stops right before that at `v.begin()`. The ranges you are querying for the largest element in the last two lines contain only a single element.